# Download HTML data without importing module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am using the `buildozer` tool so `requests`, `urllib`, `urllib2` and `urllib3` are not available to use by default. They would require manual creation of a C recipe for them to work with `buildozer`. I have no knowledge of C so not really possible.

Using Python, are there any methods to download html data from a url to a variable without requiring any modules to be imported in?
I don't mind if it's a longer process then required by the above modules, as I have no choice lol

Comment: The `buildozer` documentation (http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specifications.html) mentions that you can specify requirements that are pure Python packages.  `requirements = requests`

Comment: @mattdonders Unfortunately with Python3, using the python3crystax ndk it does not work. This has been confirmed by multiple users

Answer (score 1):

[urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) is a native library and it appears that buildozer has (buggy) support.

More information is available in [this bug report](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/187) on the buildozer page!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets:

```
import socket
class WebData:
  def __init__(self, url):
     self.url = url
  @property
  def page_data(self):
     return self.webpage_data
  def __enter__(self):
     self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     self.s.connect((self.url , 80))
     self.s.sendall("GET http://{} HTTP/1.0\n\n".format(self.url))
     self.webpage_data = self.s.recv(4096)
     return self
  def __exit__(self, *args):
     self.s.close()

with WebData('www.python.org') as f:
   print(f.page_data)
```